# How do i use my web server instead of localhost for a messaging chat app?

Tags: jquery, server, localhost, chat

I got some code from a youtube tutorial explaining how to build a live chat app with jquery and php, using your localhost server (XAMPP) and it works nicely. Here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOcFFJr2YdE

Problem:
My issue is when i attempt to recreate the same thing on my web server in cpanel in phpMyAdmin, the app doesn't work anymore, i'm pretty sure there's a problem with this line in the php file: 
$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","chat"); since i do not know what to fill in instead of localhost and root.

Here's my files:

chat.php

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","chat");
if($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed:. $db->connect_error");
} 

$result = array();
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : null;
$from = isset($_POST['from']) ? $_POST['from'] : null;

if(!empty($message) && !empty($from)) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `chat` (`message`,`from`) VALUE ('".$message."','".$from."')";
    $result['send_status'] = $db->query($sql);
}

//print messages
$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? intval($_GET['start']) : 0;
$items = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `id` >" . $start);
while($row = $items->fetch_assoc()){ 
    $result['items'][] = $row;
}  



$db->close();  


header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($result);
```

index.html

```
<body>
    <div id="messages"></div>
    <form>
    <input type="text" id="message" autocomplete="off" autofocus placeholder="Type message">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
```

index.js

```
var from = null;
var start = 0;
var url = 'http://localhost/chat.php';

$(document).ready(function() {

from = prompt('Please enter your name');

$('form').submit(function(e) {
    $.post(url, {
        message: $('#message').val(),
        from: from
    });
    $('#message').val('');

    return false;
});    

setInterval(function() {
    load();
},500)


}); 


function load() {
    $.get(url + '?start=' + start, function(result) {
        if(result.items) {
            result.items.forEach(item => {
            start = item.id;
            $('#messages').append(renderMessage(item));    
            });
            $('#messages').animate({scrollTop: $('#messages')[0].scrollHeight}); 
        }  

    }); 

}      

function renderMessage(item) {
        let time = new Date(item.created);
        time = `${time.getHours()}:${time.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : }       ${time.getMinutes()}`;
        return `<div class="msg"><p>${item.from}</p>${item.message}<span>${time</span></div>`; 
}
```

Remeber it works on localhost server but not on my web server, so has nothing to do with any html or js code per say but probably with linking the correct server or path or something similar.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: "Doesn't work anymore" isn't a sufficiently detailed diagnostic. **Check your server's error log**.

Comment: I specifically detailed where the issue is, its obviously what to repalce with localhost and root, because a web server isn't using localhost...so the problem is pretty clear.

Comment: That's just one of a multitude of problems, but in that particular case you **must** separate your database credentials from your web root. Have a configuration file that defines how to connect. Any framework like [Laravel](https://laravel.com) will have conventions on how to do this neatly and consistently. As this is a custom script you'll have to figure that out on your own, but [`parse_ini_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) is a good place to start.

Comment: In short, if you have **hard-coded credentials** in your code you have a problem and you should fix that first.

Comment: i dont understand where are my hard coded credentials? please show me which line

Comment: Literally right here: `new mysqli("localhost","root","","chat");`.

Comment: Your `index.js` should also omit the hostname from the URL as that can be determined automatically. Try: `var url = '/chat.php';` instead. Remember it's 2020, HTTPS is free and should be used on *everything*.

Comment: ok but this app is never going to be released commercially, its just a fun thing im doing. Is it still exposing security of my web server?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Your problem is relating to hard-coded credentials. You don't want to have to edit the code and deploy that, then change it back to work locally. That's a completely unsustainable development approach. Use configuration files. Keep them out of the web root. Your local copy has an INI with the "localhost" credentials, the server has a different one with whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace this line

`$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","chat");` 
with your actual database parameters.
The line should look this way:

`//Replace with the actual parameters
$db = mysqli_connect("servername","dbname","password","username");`

The server name is mostly localhost.

Comment: didn't work... are you sure of this? - do you have any sources?

Comment: Actually, the parameters are server, username, user_password, database_name... https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: with XAMPP your server will most likely be localhost,  the database name, user, and password you would have created through the XAMPP MySQL Admin

Comment: this is the error im getting
jquery.min.js:2 GET https://flexrweb.com/chat/chat.php?start=0 net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: is the chat.php script on your server or is that an external domain you are hitting?  It could be  problem with permissions, or the script is not properly configured.

Comment: its in my web server in my cpanel, same place where my db is

Comment: What are the permissions on chat.php?   If I go there in my browser I get a 404

Answer (score 0):

So in cpanel, you will want to not only create the `database user` and the password for that user, but you also need to create the `database` and then ADD THE USER TO THE DATABASE!

If you have done all that, you will want to include those credentials in your referenced line of code...

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","myUsername","myPassword","myDatabaseName");
```

If you are running this code on a different server than the database is set up on you will need to change `localhost` to the actual IP or domain name of your database which should be available through cpanel.

If this still doesn't work, please let me know what error you are getting back.  Thanks!

Comment: yes i did all of that before and im still getting error
13jquery.min.js:2 GET https://flexrweb.com/chat.php?start=0 404 (Not Found)
and
jquery.min.js:2 POST https://flexrweb.com/chat.php 404 (Not Found)

Comment: So you are getting a 404 error with the corrected url (with one /chat) ?  That is your ajax calls 404ing,  any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried putting the domain name instead of localhost when setting `url` in index.js?  `var url = 'http://flexrweb.com/chat.php';`

Comment: you can open the link and check out the code to see what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

In Cpanel - create a database user (and password) and a new database for your app.  Use these instead.

mysqli_connect('localhost', $username, $password, $database);

As far as your second error - first and foremost - the server cannot find the page /chat/chat.php (file does not exist under this directory).  /chat.php loads, but the db connection properties are wrong.

Ensure that the chat.php file you are targeting is under the following directory 
WEBROOT/web.

Your jquery error is actually at root from the css3-animate-it package you are using.  Disable it until you have figured out your connection / chat error.